# Linear mouse movement in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I am trying to find a good way to make the mouse movement smoother then just "warping" around. I used to use [this code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913646/c-sharp-moving-the-mouse-around-realistically) and so I thought I could convert it into Swift. This is what I've got so far but the app crashes as soon as I click the button. What's going wrong?

```
 @IBAction func btnMove(_ sender: Any) {

    var test: NSPoint = NSMakePoint(200, 150)
    LinearMovement(newPosition: test)


    }


func LinearMovement(newPosition: NSPoint) {
    let n = Int(readLine()!)!

    var start: NSPoint! = NSMakePoint(self.mouseLocation.x, self.mouseLocation.y)
    var iterPoint: NSPoint! = start
    var slope: NSPoint! = NSPoint(x: newPosition.x - start.x, y: newPosition.y - start.y)


    //  Convert CGFloat to Int
    var myIntValuex:Int = Int(slope.x)
    var myIntValuey:Int = Int(slope.y)
    // Devide by the number of steps
    var slopex = myIntValuex / n
    var slopey = myIntValuey / n


    //  Move the mouse to each iterative point.

    for i in 0 ..< n  {

        var intIterx:Int = Int(iterPoint.x)
        var intItery:Int = Int(iterPoint.y)

        var iterPointx = intIterx + slopex
        var iterPointy = intItery + slopey

        var iterPointf: NSPoint = NSPoint(x: iterPointx, y: iterPointy)


        CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(iterPointf)
       //  Thread.Sleep(MouseEventDelayMS)   ??????
    }

    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(newPosition)
}
```

Comment: How exactly does the app crash? What is printed into the console? At the moment it just looks like you're blocking the main thread which makes your application unresponsive.

Comment: It just stops working. "Application is not responding"

Comment: Did you run the application in a debugger and paused it while you're having this issue?

Comment: When I put a breakpoint after  `let n = Int(readLine()!)! ` it crashes already

Comment: So it does crash? Then Xcode should show you the line in which the code crashed and print into the console why it crashed.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-06-23 17:43:20.844214 Mouse Movement SWIFT[52636:9068644] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back at this I fixed this problem. The problem was that `readLine()` didn't have any input. I now replaced this with and Int called `steps` which I give an input. (A number of how many steps between the start position of the cursor and the final position of the cursor.

To flip the y-axis for correct reading with all the location points:

```
var start = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let screenheight = NSScreen.main?.frame.height
        
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved)
            {
            self.start = NSEvent.mouseLocation
            self.start.y = screenheight! - self.start.y
            print(self.start)
            return $0
            
        }
```

The function itself:

```
func LinearMovement(newPosition: NSPoint, steps: Int) {
        
        var iterPoint: NSPoint = start
        var slope: NSPoint = NSPoint(x: newPosition.x - start.x, y: newPosition.y - start.y)

            // Divide by the number of steps
        slope.x = slope.x / CGFloat(steps)
        print(slope.x)
        slope.y = slope.y / CGFloat(steps)
        print(slope.y)

            // Move the mouse to each iterative point.
        for i in 0 ..< steps
            {
            
            let randomtime = Int.random(in: 150..<300)
            iterPoint = NSPoint(x: iterPoint.x + slope.x, y: iterPoint.y + slope.y)
            print(randomtime)
                CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(iterPoint)
            do {
                usleep(UInt32(randomtime))
                }
            
            }

            // Move the mouse to the final destination.
            CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(newPosition)
        start = newPosition
        print(start)
        }
```

And to call the function:

```
var newloc = CGPoint(x: 200 , y: 200)
LinearMovement(newPosition: newloc, steps: 1920)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the console message you got it looks like either `readLine()` or `Int(readLine()!)` returns nil. If you're force unwrapping an optional value and the value is nil your app will crash.

**Only force unwrap if you're absolutely 100% sure the value you're unwrapping will NEVER be nil!**

To avoid these kinds of crashes unwrap with `if let` or `guard let` statements:

```
guard let line = readLine() else {
    // handle the error appropriately here
    // readLine() may return nil if STDIN was closed
    print("Could not read line")
    return
}
guard let n = Int(line) else {
    // handle the error appropriately here
    // Int(line) returns nil if line is not a valid Integer string
    print("Expected an Int value")
    return // or whatever fits here
}
```

You can - with some modification - do this in a loop so if the user enters an invalid value he can try again.

Comment: Okay this now just keeps giving me "Could not read". Would you know how to fix my code that it does the linear mouse movement?

Comment: It looks like you're closing your standard input stream (e.g. by not launching your app in a Terminal). You have to use another way to get the user input, for example by using a text field, a slider or something similar.