# InputSimulator smooth linear mouse movement between 2 points

Tags: c#, ui-automation, inputsimulator

I'm struggling to figure out why the below function is only ever moving my mouse from 0, 0 screen coords, to my final destination, even though Cursor.Position is returning the correct screen coords. If anybody could enlighten me i'd be most grateful.

```
public void MoveAndClick(int x, int y, int steps)
{
    Point start = Cursor.Position;
    PointF iterPoint = start;

    PointF slope = new PointF(x - start.X, y - start.Y);
    slope.X = slope.X / steps;
    slope.Y = slope.Y / steps;

    for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
    {
        iterPoint = new PointF(iterPoint.X + slope.X, iterPoint.Y + slope.Y);
        inputSim.Mouse.MoveMouseTo(iterPoint.X, iterPoint.Y);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    inputSim.Mouse.MoveMouseTo(x, y);
    inputSim.Mouse.RightButtonDown();
    inputSim.Mouse.RightButtonUp();
}
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/913703/2014393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOH! Always stop working when you're sleepy and go to bed.

The InputSimulator library requires that you translate coordinates like so:

```
int startX = 65535 * Cursor.Position.X / Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int startY = 65535 * Cursor.Position.Y / Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

I was converting the end coordinates but completely forgot to translate the starting coordinates, derp.

Answer (score 0):

FlaUI allows for the mouse to move smoothly. Here is the [Mouse](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.Core/Input/Mouse.cs#L94) class in FlaUI for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void MoverSuavementePara(string arg)
{
    (int, int) pos = RegexHelper.pos_math(arg);
    int endX = (int)(pos.Item1 * Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
    int endY = (int)(pos.Item2 * Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    (int, int) cord_start = NormalizarCoordenadas(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y); 
    int startX = cord_start.Item1;
    int startY = cord_start.Item2;
    
    int duracao = 890;

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    while ((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds <= duracao)
    {
        double progress = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds / duracao;
        int currentX = (int)(startX + progress * (endX - startX));
        int currentY = (int)(startY + progress * (endY - startY));

        Inputer.inputer.Mouse.MoveMouseTo(currentX, currentY);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    Inputer.inputer.Mouse.MoveMouseTo(endX, endY);
}


static (int, int) NormalizarCoordenadas(int x, int y)
{
    return (
        NormalizarCoordenada(x, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Right, 65535),
        NormalizarCoordenada(y, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Bottom, 65535)
    );
}

static int NormalizarCoordenada(int coordenada, int telaMin, int telaMax, int alvoMax)
{
    return (int)((double)(coordenada - telaMin) / (telaMax - telaMin) * alvoMax);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rafael! Please [edit] your answer to translate the non-English variables, and to remove unrelated parts (instead of telling readers to ignore them), that would be help to future readers immensely. I also suggest taking the [tour] and reading [answer] to better understand how to contribute to Stack Overflow, as this is not a forum, but a high quality Q&A website. Thanks for contributing!